# Remembering Selected Points on Plot in Shiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I'm trying to create an interactive k-means plot that will allow people to see the effects of their inputs (like specifying centers as opposed to purely random selection) but running in to an issue with my Shiny code. I'm trying to understand how I can select a point and have my app remember it to use as a center. I've been searching for a way to do this with reactive code but everything I've tried so far has failed. My current working code is as below:

```
# Pre Work
library(ggfortify)
dsnames <- names(iris[1:4])
cb_options <- list()
cb_options[dsnames] <- dsnames

# UI
shinyUI <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Interactive K-Means Clustering Using Iris Dataset"),
  sidebarPanel(
    numericInput("numCenter", label=h4("Centers for k-means:"), min=2, max=30, value=3),
    selectInput("xaxisGrp","X-Axis:", c("1"="1","2"="2"), choices=cb_options),
    selectInput("yaxisGrp","Y-Axis:", c("1"="1","2"="2"), choices=cb_options),
    tableOutput("info")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot1", click="plot_click", dblclick="plot_dbl")
  )
)

# Server
shinyServer <- function(input, output, session) {

  iris_k <- reactive({
    kmeans(iris[1:4], centers=input$numCenter)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot() + geom_point(data=iris, aes_string(input$xaxisGrp, input$yaxisGrp), colour=iris_k()$cluster)
  })

  output$info <- renderTable({
    nearPoints(iris, input$plot_click, xvar=input$xaxisGrp, yvar=input$yaxisGrp)[,c(input$xaxisGrp, input$yaxisGrp)]
  })

}

# ShinyApp function call
shinyApp(ui=shinyUI, server=shinyServer)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've managed to figure this one out after finding some flaws in my working code. If this answer will help anyone else, I'll be glad. The new Shiny Server code uses `reactiveValues()` which hadn't been working before because I'd misunderstood their use. The new code segment is:

```
   v <- reactiveValues(
     selectedData = NULL
     )

   observeEvent(input$plot_dbl, {
     X1 <- nearPoints(iris, input$plot_dbl)
     if (is.null(v$selectedData)) {
       v$selectedData <- X1
     } else {
       if (nrow(merge(X1, v$selectedData)) > 0) {
         ind <- anyDuplicated(rbind(v$selectedData, X1), fromLast=TRUE)
         v$selectedData <- v$selectedData[-ind,]
       } else {
         v$selectedData <- rbind(v$selectedData, X1)
       }
     }
   })
```

This has allowed me to select plotted points on a graph and remember them as I wished.